# Populating large matrix with values

Tags: python, numpy, dask

I have a 100K by 12 by 100K matrix that I need to populate with computation results.  I tried creating it using numpy.empty but got a memory error.

So I turned to dask instead.  I'm able to create the dask array.  I'm running a function that creates a vector as I traverse through the 0th and 1st dimension in a for loop.  I then populate this vector into the i,jth position of the matrix.  If I just populate the dask array as is, just the assignment step takes 50 milliseconds, which is way too long when extrapolated for all atomic cells in the matrix.

It seems it should be possible to speed up the assignment with dask's delayed function, but can't figure it out.

Here's how this would look without delay:

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.delayed as delayed
from dask import compute
import numpy as np

test_arr = da.empty(shape=(10000, 12, 10000), dtype='float32')
for i in range(test_arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(test_arr.shape[1]):
        vals = np.random.normal(size=test_arr.shape[2])
        test_arr[i,j,:] = vals
```

And here is my attempt at using delay:

```
def populate_array(i, j, vec):
    test_arr[i, j, :] = vec
    return test_arr

for i in range(test_arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(test_arr.shape[1]):
        vals = np.random.normal(size=test_arr.shape[2])
        delayed(populate_array)(i, j, vals)

compute(test_arr)
```

The latter doesn't error but just seems to return an array with all zeroes.
I know that I can also speed this up by getting rid of the for loop and vectorizing but assume that is currently not feasible.

I'm not tied to dask per se but it seems like a practical approach with a familiar syntax if coming from pandas / numpy.

Update:
Accepted answer works but the task stream has a lot of blank spaces.  I bring this up because my actual use case with a complex create_array_chunk formula just hangs.  Cannot see the dashboard or what's going on.

[image]

Comment: Have you done the math?  I'm not sure you're being realistic.  A 100k x 100k x 12 array of floats will be 500GB.  That's clearly outrageous.  Even your reduced 10k x 10k x 12 array will be 5GB.  Creating 1.2 billion random values is never going to be quick.

Comment: So the question is: why do you want to create such a huge matrix? Storing data in RAM is not possible here and storing it on disk will be very slow (at least few minutes). Practical experience shows that such huge matrix are rarely actually *needed*.

Comment: They're not random values, I was just using that for the purpose of this question.  Each atomic cell contains a probability density of measurements from a particular device at a particular point in time (so first 2 dimensions are time and device, 3rd dimension is probability density value of a pdf).

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're expecting, nor what you plan to do with this enormous matrix.  Your original requirement is not achievable, and filling an array with data values is not generally something that can be sped up.  Are they coming from disk?  Do you really need all 12 devices in memory at once?

Comment: Ideally would like for this to compute within 45 minutes.  I'm content with someone showing whether assignment to a matrix can be sped up using dask on a much smaller dataframe.  If such functionality doesn't exist, that's also an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it. You don't fill an existing Dask Array, you build it chunk by chunk:

```py
import dask.array as da
import dask.delayed as delayed
import numpy as np

shape = (10000, 12, 10000)

def create_array_chunk(i, j, k):
    # should use i and j information probably here
    return np.random.normal(size=k)

i_arrays = []
for i in range(shape[0]):
    j_arrays = []
    for j in range(shape[1]):
        darray = da.from_delayed(delayed(create_array_chunk)(i, j, shape[2]), dtype=np.float64, shape=(shape[2],))
        j_arrays.append(darray)
    j_stack=da.stack(j_arrays, axis=0)
    i_arrays.append(j_stack)
j_stack = da.stack(i_arrays, axis=0)
```

j_stack is a Dask Array structure of shape (10000, 12, 10000), has can be seen below:
[image: Dask Array]

It's a lazy structure, nothing has been computed yet. Be careful, if you call compute on it it will convert it to a Numpy array and take a lot of memory. You might want to stream it to disk using `to_zarr` or equivalent.

Comment: Although this works when the create_array_chunk is a dummy function like above, when I run it on my actual dataset with a much more complex set of operations in create_array_chunk it just hangs.  The dashboard is blank too and doesn't reload properly.  I noticed the task graph for the dummy code had a lot of blanks, so lots of time spent with handoff, maybe that's the issue.  I'll include a screenshot of the task screen in my original question.

Comment: The reason the task stream plot has a lot of blank is because chunks are much too small in this example, and the time taken to create them is shorter than the actual overrhead of working with Dask. More code should be moved to the delayed function.